# How to use Pandas to read CSV file with delimiter existing in the last field?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have raw data in the following format:

```
JobID,Publish,Expire,TitleAndDetail
7428,17/12/2006 2:00:00 PM,28/01/2007 2:00:00 PM,Project Engineer - Mechanical      Looking,.....,....
7429,9/03/2006 2:00:00 PM,27/02/2007 2:00:00 PM,Supply Teacher      The job is,.....,.....
```

As you can see the delimiter is comma, however the last column is a chunk of  text with commas within. **I am using pandas' `read_csv` function to read this CSV file. However in pandas dataframe the text parts after the 4th comma in each line are lost.**

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(r"/ABC/JobDetails.csv",
                       names=['JobID', 'Publish', 'Expire', 'TitleAndDetail'],
                       header=None
                       )
```

If using `string.split()` function, I can specify a `maxsplit` parameter which allows me to keep all the content in the last column even if there're many commas. Is there similar functionality in Pandas?

Comment: You should try to get a dataset with tabs as the delimiter (.tsv), it is more stable for your use case. Another alternative is to wrap your elements with double quotes " ". This would make it assume it as one combined entry escaping all the commas inside element.

Comment: Your file is not well formed; so trying things to bypass this is basically ignoring the problem (the original file should have quoted fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file manually and then create the dataframe:

```
rows = []

with open('somefile.csv') as f:
  keys = next(f).split(',')
  for line in f:
     rows.append(dict(zip(keys, line.split(',', 3))))

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

`.split` takes an optional parameter to limit the number of times it splits over the delimiter. Passing 3 means it ignores the commas in your last field:

```
>>> s.split(',', 3)
['7428',
 '17/12/2006 2:00:00 PM',
 '28/01/2007 2:00:00 PM',
 'Project Engineer - Mechanical      Looking,.....,....']
```

Next, we create a dictionary with the keys from the header row and the values from the data rows:

```
>>> f = 'JobID,Publish,Expire,TitleAndDetail'.split(',')
>>> dict(zip(f, s.split(',', 3)))
{'JobID': '7428',
 'Publish': '17/12/2006 2:00:00 PM',
 'Expire': '28/01/2007 2:00:00 PM',
 'TitleAndDetail': 'Project Engineer - Mechanical      Looking,.....,....'}
```

Finally, we make a list of these dictionaries (in `rows`), and pass this as an argument to create our data frame object.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a bit of a hack you could try:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(r"/ABC/JobDetails.csv",
                       squeeze=True,
                       sep="\a"
                       )
```

This should give you a Series by ignoring the ","s

Then you can do:

```
df = raw_data.str.split(",", n=4, expand=True)
df.columns = ['JobID', 'Publish', 'Expire', 'TitleAndDetail']
```

That should split into 4 columns and rename

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However `raw_data.str` showed an error on my computer: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`.

Comment: Yes sorry see my edit, for this to work you need to select a separator that doesn't exist in your data so nothing gets split

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=",")
    rows = [x[:3] + [','.join(x[3:])] for x in reader]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
    print df
```